# Find out if object has property without reading its contents

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

This is best explained by showing you my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "datasets": {
      "$dataset": {
        "$secureName": {
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically what the rule (should) say is: Only read and write when hitting `/datasets/$dataset/$secureName`. This is how I'm securing my application without authentication (any suggestions to make this better is great).

The problem is, I don't want to create a new `dataset` if there is an existing `dataset` of the same name.

I've tried this:

```
new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(SOME_NAME)) {
    // It exists! Don't make a new one!
  } else {
    // It doesn't exist! Make a new one!
  }
});
```

But the problem is, in `dataSnapshot` it has all the information in it which doesn't make my app very secure. Any tips would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but there is the [in  operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7), e.g. `if (SOME_NAME in dataSnapshot)` and also the [hasOwnPrpoerty method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5), e.g. `if (dataSnapshot.hasOwnProperty(SOME_NAME))`. Both test for the existence of a property without reading the value.

Comment: @RobG that's actually not true. `dataSnapshot` itself contains all of the data. So a person could put a breakpoint in my code in their browser and get access to all the data in dataSnapshot.

Comment: It is exactly true: both suggestions allow you to test for the existence of a property whether it has been assigned a value or not (you could also use [Object.keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14)). How you choose to protect the data that may or may not be assigned to the property is a different matter (and may be what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

Change you security rule to allow writes only if the dataset doesn't exist:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "datasets": {
      "$dataset": {
        "$secureName": {
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "!data.exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you give me still allows there to be multiple $secureNames per $dataset. My end goal is to make it so no dataset has more than one child. That would accomplish my purpose I think... I don't believe this is currently possible. I'll submit a ticket.

Comment: You can do this by assigning fixed names to children of datasets, for example: {"$dataset": {"$name": {".write": "$name == 'fixedName'"}}}